# selecting the correct letter from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring, patindex

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl (m VARCHAR(100))  
INSERT INTO #tmpTbl VALUES
 (',[Undergraduate1]')    
,(',[Undergraduate10]')   
,(',[Undergraduate11]')   
;
GO

select LEFT(m, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m)-1) as a,
         SUBSTRING(m, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m), LEN(m)) as b from #tmpTbl


drop table #tmpTbl
```

Hi given the above tmptable and select statement, the result will be as follow.

```
           a            |      b
-------------------------------------------------------
    ,[Undergraduate     |      1]
    ,[Undergraduate     |      10]
    ,[Undergraduate     |      11]
```

However i want it to be like this.

```
           a            |      b
-------------------------------------------------------
    ,[Undergraduate     |      1
    ,[Undergraduate     |      10
    ,[Undergraduate     |      11
```

How can i achieve that? i tried alot of combination with PATINDEX, LEFT, RIGHT, SUBSTRING,LEN. but cant get right of the ] in column B

Comment: `SUBSTRING(m, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m), LEN(m) - 1)` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use replace to remove the ]. Dodgy, but it achieves what you want

```
select LEFT(m, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m)-1) as a,
     REPLACE(SUBSTRING(m, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m), LEN(m)),']','') as b from #tmpTbl
```

*alternative:* reverse the string, substring to remove 1st char, reverse back

```
select LEFT(m, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m)-1) as a,
         REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(m, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m), LEN(m))),2,LEN(M))) as b from #tmpTbl
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `REPLACE` to replace `]` with `''`

```
select LEFT(m, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m)-1) as a,
         REPLACE(SUBSTRING(m, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m), LEN(m)), ']', '') as b from #tmpTbl
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm inclined to use `stuff()` for this purpose:

```
select replace(stuff(m, 1, patindex(m, '%[0-9]%'), ''), ']', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach that will strip any text and just leave the numbers behind.

```
SELECT LEFT(subsrt, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', subsrt + 't') - 1) 
FROM (
    SELECT subsrt = SUBSTRING(m, pos, LEN(m))
    FROM (
        SELECT m, pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', m)
        FROM #tmpTbl
    ) d
) t
```